# Error while enrolling Admin User using enrollAdmin.js in fabcar

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I am following this URL for writing First Application

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/write_first_app.html

I recently updated the Fabric to v1.2 and thought of going through this exercise.

I am getting an error while enrolling the Admin User using

"node enrollAdmin.js"

I am running this from fabcar sub-directory of fabric-samples. Getting below error(Error Screenshot attached below)

Node version: 6.9.5

package.json --dependencies:

fabric-ca-client: unstable
fabric-client: unstable

As I was not clear on how to upgrade the Fabric CA Server thus haven't upgraded it by using the following URL

http://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users-guide.html#upgrading-the-server

Thusly, couldn't update the Node SDK Client as updating the Fabric CA Server was a pre-requisite.
npm install fabric-client@1.2
npm install fabric-ca-client@1.2

Error Screenshot

[image]

Comment: You need to upgrade to Node version 8.x

Comment: Hi Gari, Thanks for your comments. Do I need to update Fabric CA Server before that or just updating the Node will work?

Comment: For the particular error above, just upgrading Node should work (I'm pretty sure the error is due to the fact that "async" was only added in Node v8.x)

Comment: Yes, you are right, I have checked the documentation as well. Have updated the Node to v8.11.3. Now getting an error while bringing up the network using "startFabric.sh" script from fabcar sub-directory of fabric-samples. I am getting below error.

cannot start ca.example.com: b'network 58c33d3952bed36d6dabfc8cf114af20c1febe861f39237e9d64ca4f1975b188 not found

Comment: I deleted the docker images and ran startFabric again and it seems that It is now working. Thanks for your help.